# Convert Years into months and months into Year

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two text boxes one for year and one for month. If I enter 19 into month text box, then in the years text box it should calculate to 1.7 and if I type 1.7 into years text box then it should be 19 month into the month text box. I need a function which basically calculate this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](/tour) (you get a badge!) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: "I need a function which basically calculate this." Please try writing such a function yourself before posting here.  Stackoverflow *is not* a free coding service.

Comment: where the `1.7` comes from?

Comment: @appleapple Probably  19 months = 1 year and 7 months

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava oh, yes that'd make sense :)

Comment: @appleapple 19 months = 1 year and 7 months

Comment: why do you want to write 1.7 from 19 months. If you still want to separate whole years and the months then consider integer division to get the years. Use mod division to get the reminder to get the months in decimals and multiply it by 12 to get the whole number. As pointed by @Dexygen you need to write your own code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Year Month Conversion

### Criteria

1. Months->Years
   Year values will be represented as `<Year>.<Month>` and not a
   fraction of years; e.g., `1.7 years` means 1 year 7 months and not
   20.4 months
2. Years->Months
   The same considerations are given.  A fractional year is converted into year and months; e.g., `1.12 years` means 1 year 12 months and not 1 year 1.44 months

### Explanation

The implementation below consists of displaying the years as a string and the months as a numeric value.  The years can be obtained from months by dividing the month count by 12.  The remaining months are found by taking the month entry and taking the remainder of 12 (modulus 12).  These can be combined via string operators.

***Note:*** It is really important to consider that `1.12` is actually greater than `1.9`.  This is the notation requested and not one that is preferred.  If someone is to continue this path, I might encourage to use `1.09` (as opposed to `1.9`) to represent 1 year 9 months.  This way it's clear 1.12 is larger than 1.09.  Additionally, it would allow for entering in larger months; e.g., 0.20 years should translate to 20 months, but because `.2` and `.20` are synonymous, it would 0.20 only translates to 2 months.

### Example

You can add event listeners and calculate how you deem fit:

```js
year.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
  let fraction = parseFloat(this.value) - (this.value|0);
  let months = Math.round(fraction*100)
  if (months % 10 == 0) months = months/10
  month.value = parseInt(this.value) * 12 + months

  if (this.value == '')
    month.value = ''
});

month.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
  let years  = parseFloat(this.value)
  year.value = parseInt(years / 12) + '.' + parseInt(years%12)
  
  if (this.value == '')
    year.value = ''
});

document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if(e.target.type == 'text')
    e.target.value = ''
});
```

```html
Year: <input type="text" id="year" />
Month: <input type="text" id="month" />
```

Comment: You need to use the [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder) for this (`19 % 12 === 7`) - This answer is incorrect unfortunately

Comment: 19 should come out to 1.7 at the end.

Comment: @AlonEitan You beat me to it.  First phase was to take the fraction and multiply, second is to mod it.  Nice job!

Comment: @ImranAhmadMughal if you enter 1.12 years, do you expect 13.2 months or 24 months?